# Does "region" in "region lock" mean the PS4 device's region or the logged in account's region?

Tags: ps4, region-lock

I bought my PS4 in Vietnam and logged in with an account which I registered the location as USA. There seems to be a region lock for DLC so I want to determine my region before buying the game.

Comment: from my experience with the PS3 and PSN Accounts on it the console shouldn't have anything to do with DLC Region Lock. DLC must generally match the region of the game as such any DLC you buy with your US PSN Account will only work with US Games (if i recall will have a small globe icon on the back with the number 1, Region 1). though i say generally because Australian DLC can work with both Australian and UK Games (Regions 4 and 2). for the PS4 i haven't had any need to get US Games but i don't really see it being different since my Aus, UK and US all worked on it like on my PS3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two region matters you need to be aware of. The first one is console region and the second is DLC pairing:

- The vast majority of PS4 games are region-free in regards to console region. If you happen to find a game that **is** locked, although rare, you'll have to buy the vietnamese version of that game (or some other shared version). Those are usually japanese games.
- DLC is usually locked to a specific **game id**. That ID may or may not change between regions or between specific regions. For example, US games are usually compatible with Latin America DLC. What matters here is that you buy the DLC of the same region as the game itself, the console doesn't matter. So you can buy a game from the UK, create an UK PSN account to buy DLC, and play the game in your US account with your vietnamese console. If you buy a game in the US, everything will work fine on your US account.